# Using VBS and the registry to determine which version and 32 vs. 64 bit oracle drivers are installed

Tags: oracle, vbscript

I'd like to use VBS to read the registry to list some info on a server including the drivers.

**VBS:**

```
REM Run this file with the following command:
REM cscript  drivers.vbs | clip

WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

'Get Server Name
Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Network" )
strComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName
WScript.Echo "Computer Name: " & strComputerName

'Get Driver Names  
strComputer = "."
 
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
 
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
objRegistry.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes


For i = 0 to UBound(arrValueNames)
    strValueName = arrValueNames(i)
    objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue    
    Wscript.Echo arrValueNames(i) & " -- " & strValue
Next

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Get Oracle Environment variables
WScript.Echo "TNS_ADMIN=" & objShell.Environment("SYSTEM").Item("TNS_ADMIN")
WScript.Echo "ORACLE_HOME=" & objShell.Environment("SYSTEM").Item("ORACLE_HOME")


WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------
Computer Name: WLDL2532
SQL Server -- Installed
Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit) -- Installed
iSeries Access ODBC Driver -- Installed
SQL Server Native Client 10.0 -- Installed
**Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 -- Installed**
IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2_976_64 -- Installed
IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER -- Installed
ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server -- Installed
DataDirect 6.1 Sybase Wire Protocol -- Installed
SQL Server Native Client 11.0 -- Installed
TNS_ADMIN=C:\WINDOWS\TNS
ORACLE_HOME=
------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to know how to separately list if the 32 bit driver or the 64 bit Oracle driver is installed. I have both on my machine, but it doesn't indicate which. Presumably, it can mean both or either, I assume. Normally, if a 32 bit driver were found, I'd expect to see "32" in the name.

Also, I'd be interested to know where to best look in the registry for this info.

Comment: 32 bit drivers are located in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC

Comment: Is my code current confirming a 64 bit oracle driver or just a non specific oracle driver? Ie, should I look found another key to confirm the presence of a 64 bit driver?

Comment: That depends on how you run it. If you call it with a 64Bit scripting host it should report the 64bit driver, if you run it with a 32Bit scripting host it would report the 32Bit driver. Do you have control over which scripting host is used or is it called from another application (in this case it would by default only use 64Bit if the application was 64Bit as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your VBS code the question should be: *Using VBS and the registry to determine which version and 32 vs. 64 bit of **ODBC** drivers are installed*

There are many other drivers available for Oracle, e.g. OleDB, ODP.NET, JDBC, etc.

In order to get 32 and 64 bit you can do it in two ways

Either run the VBS in different scripting host, i.e.

```
For 64 Bit: >c:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe Drivers.vbs
For 32 Bit: >c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe Drivers.vbs
```

Or modify the VBS script in order to interrogate 32 and 64 Bit path in Registry:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
objRegistry.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes

For i = 0 to UBound(arrValueNames)
    strValueName = arrValueNames(i)
    objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue    
    Wscript.Echo arrValueNames(i) & " -- 64 Bit " & strValue
Next

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
objRegistry.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes

For i = 0 to UBound(arrValueNames)
    strValueName = arrValueNames(i)
    objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue    
    Wscript.Echo arrValueNames(i) & " -- 32 Bit " & strValue
Next
```

Another note: `TNS_ADMIN`and `ORACLE_HOME` can be defined by environment variable, however you can defined them also in the Registry. Check for 64 bit

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\Key_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN 
and 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\Key_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\ORACLE_HOME
```

and for 32 bit

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\Key_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN
and
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\Key_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\ORACLE_HOME
```

Comment: Thank you!. I posted a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326892/identifying-the-location-of-the-relevant-tnsnames-and-echoing-to-the-console

Comment: I'm getting two different result depending on whether I use the VBS you provided or the 64 bit and 32 bit version of cscipt with my original vbs. Confusing.

Comment: Yes, of course. When you run a 32bit application on 64bit Windows then it runs like in another virtual 32bit windows environment. You cannot access folders like `C:\Windows\System32` or registry path like `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE`. They are automatically redirected to `c:\Windows\SysWOW64` resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE`. 

Have a look at [How Windows 64-bit Supports 32-bit Applications](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm) in order to get more details.