# Identifying the location of the relevant tnsnames and echoing to the console

Tags: oracle, vbscript, registry

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310643/using-vbs-and-the-registry-to-determine-which-version-and-32-vs-64-bit-oracle-d), I was working on using VBS to list all of the drivers installed on a machine. I am particularly interested in the Oracle drivers.

Now, I'd like to next capture the contents of the applicable tnsnames.ora files.  In practice in our environment, I would expect up to 3 tnsnames.ora files with the assumption that a machine might have both the 32 bit and 64 bit drivers installed. I would then expect 1 tnnamesora file in the 32 bit admin folder, 1 in the 63 bit folder and one in the %TNS_ADMIN% folder, if there is a system variable defined for %TNS_ADMIN%. On my machine, my %TNS_ADMIN% system variable is set to C:\Windows\TNS and once set, I need not have a separate tbnsnames.ora file in the 32 and 64 bit locations. The one in the %TNS_ADMIN% location if defined, will be used by either driver. On my PC the 32 and 64 bit tnsnames.ora file locations are:

```
C:\Oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
C:\Oracle\product\11203_64bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
```

What I would like to do is to identify these locations using VBS to read the registry and then use the TYPE command on each file to echo the contents to the console using the code of my previous post as a starting point.

I've been poking around in the registry trying to find the relevant keys or chain of keys to get this info. With that info, I may be able to figure out the code.

```
REM Run this file with the following command:
REM cscript  ListDriversV2.vbs | clip

WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"

'Get Server Name
Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Network" )
strComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName
WScript.Echo "Computer Name: " & strComputerName

'List 64 bit drivers
WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "List 64 bit drivers:"
WScript.Echo 

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
objRegistry.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes

For i = 0 to UBound(arrValueNames)
    strValueName = arrValueNames(i)
    objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue    
    Wscript.Echo arrValueNames(i) & " -- 64 Bit " & strValue
Next

'List 32 bit drivers
WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "List 32 bit drivers:"
WScript.Echo 

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
objRegistry.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes

For i = 0 to UBound(arrValueNames)
    strValueName = arrValueNames(i)
    objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue    
    Wscript.Echo arrValueNames(i) & " -- 32 Bit " & strValue
Next


'List Oracle Environment variables

WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "List Oracle Environment variables:"
WScript.Echo 

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strTnsAdmin = objShell.Environment("SYSTEM").Item("TNS_ADMIN")
WScript.Echo "TNS_ADMIN=" & strTnsAdmin

strOracleHome = objShell.Environment("SYSTEM").Item("ORACLE_HOME")
WScript.Echo "ORACLE_HOME=" & stroracleHome


WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "List All System Environment variables:"
WScript.Echo 

Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("SYSTEM")

For Each strVar in objEnv
  WScript.Echo strVar
Next

WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
WScript.Echo "List All User Environment variables:"
WScript.Echo 

Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("User")

For Each strVar in objEnv
  WScript.Echo strVar
Next


WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
'How do I dynamically determine this Oracle 64 bit tnsnames location location from the registry?
strPath = "E:\oracle_12101_64bit\product\12101_64bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\"

WScript.Echo "Dump " & strPath
WScript.Echo 

strFileContent = LoadStringFromFile(strPath)

WScript.Echo LoadStringFromFile(strPath)
WScript.Echo strPath

WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
'How do I dynamically determine this Oracle 32 bit tnsnames location location from the registry?
strPath = "E:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_32Bit\NETWORK\ADMIN\TNSNAMES.ORA"
WScript.Echo "Dump " & strPath
WScript.Echo 

strFileContent = LoadStringFromFile(strPath)

WScript.Echo LoadStringFromFile(strPath)
WScript.Echo strPath

WScript.Echo "------------------------------------------------"
strPath = strTnsAdmin & "\tnsnames.ora"
WScript.Echo "Dump " & strPath
WScript.Echo 

strFileContent = LoadStringFromFile(strPath)

WScript.Echo LoadStringFromFile(strPath)
WScript.Echo strPath

Function LoadStringFromFile(filename)
    Const fsoForReading = 1
    Const fsoForWriting = 2
    Dim fso, f
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fso.FileExists(filename) Then
        Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, fsoForReading)
        LoadStringFromFile = f.ReadAll
        f.Close
    Else
        LoadStringFromFile = ""
    End if
        
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

According Oracle these locations are searched for `tnsnames.ora`, resp. `sqlnet.ora`:

1. current path (associated with the running client application)
2. Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` defined for the session
3. Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` defined for the system
4. Windows Registry Key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN` (for 64 bit) or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN` (for 32 bit)
5. `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`

However, I am not sure whether each application/driver/version follows this list. This list was provided by Oracle related to version 9i.
I think you will manage it to query these folders by VBScript.

If `ORACLE_HOME` is not set by Environment variable, you have to query the Registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\ORACLE_HOME` (for 64 bit) or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\ORACLE_HOME` (for 32 bit)

For `ORACLE_HOME_NAME` you have to navigate to your Oracle `bin` folder (to be found via `%PATH%` Environment variable) and open file `oracle.key`. This is a simple text file containing only the `ORACLE_HOME_NAME` value, e.g. *OraClient11g_home1*.

However, typically there is only one Oracle Home underneath `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE`, so seeking and reading file `oracle.key` might be an overkill.

**Update**

When I run a test on my machine (with Oracle Client 11.2) I get following order:

1. Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`
2. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`, resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN` -> **Only if `TNS_ADMIN` Environment variable is not set.**
3. `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`
4. Current directory (which can be different to directory where your application is located)
5. Folder where your application is located

For a deep analysis you have to search for `tnsnames.ora`, `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora`. The Oracle database name can be resolved through each of them, i.e. a connection may be established even when `tnsnames.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` do not exist.

Comment: I'm confused on how you locate the oracle bin folder "via the %path% env variable." The Path env variable contains a million folders separated by colons. Does it check one at a time in order until it find a folder with a file called oracle.key in it?

Comment: Well, not "million folders", typically 10-30 folders. Actually `oracle.key` is sought by some Oracle DLL's which are found by `%PATH%` themselves.

Comment: In my environment, oracle.key file's content is `SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1_32bit`